# JQuery Mobile Listview Background Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, mobile

How can I adjust the background color of a listview item in jquery mobile?  Basically I'd like a user to click a item and have it and only it highlight, very simple, so I thought.

I thought this might achieve it (.groupList is an unordered list with that class).  The event is fired but nothing changes.

```
 $(".groupList li").bind('click', function() {
    logger.debug("list row click");

    $(this).closest("li").siblings().attr("data-theme","a");
    $(this).parents("li").attr("data-theme","e");
});
```

I think the reason this is broken has to do with the fact I can't seem to set data-theme dynamically at all on listviews.  I also can't use the background-color css with any luck.

It seems li tags can only have their data-theme set before appending to a list, once appended I can't get it to change.

The logic I've described here works on table rows just fine.  Just bind the click event to tbody tr.  The jquery functions closest, siblings and parent help us turn on/off the css for the background color.  Again, not entirely sure why a listview breaks this.